# fixed position broken on contentEditable ios webkit safari

Tags: ios, safari, webkit, contenteditable, css-position

I want to create a `wysiwyg-editor` for `ipad` and have a toolbar with `position:fixed` - so that it's always available.

However, when I focus on `div` with `contentEditable="true"` the toolbar is not fixed any more.

Is this a bug?

Is there a workaround?

Comment: I want this too. Nothing I've come up with so far quite cuts it.

Comment: there is abug in mobile safari with contentEditable. Please see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=371646

Answer (score 1):

just found this while looking for the same thing - for the same reason...

we have a half-way solution to the toolbar, but it sort of wanders off-page and then resets to the correct position when the scroll finally stops. The solution isnt pushed to github yet, but it will be in the next couple of days. Best approach we have so far is a chunk of JS that forces the div back in place if we recognise we are working on iOS :-(

But you might want to check the editor we built in any case :-) http://www.quink.mobi or https://github.com/IMD-Business-School/Quink.